# Shooter Rotation Calculations

Tags: rotation, phaser-framework

I am making a simple JavaScript game using Phaser and it is [going pretty well](http://tanks.mattrick.me/). I am currently having a few issues with the rotation of the tank, however.

**Issue 1:**
<strike>When shooting the bullet (left click) the speed is dependent on the distance from the tank to the mouse. The code I am currently using to get the rotation of the tank involves subtracting the mouse x and y from the tank x and y. The bullet receives the velocity from these values. How would I go about keeping the velocity consistent no matter what the distance of the mouse is?</strike>
Phaser has a [native method](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#moveToPointer) for this I did not know about.

**Issue 2:**
If you click to shoot a bullet and turn quickly, you can see the bullet under the barrel of the tank. This is more a a visual "glitch", but I would like to have the bullet spawn right at the edge of the barrel of the tank. Is there a method to get the correct spawn location based on both the rotation and barrel position?

Comment: Have you tried toying with [sprite.pivot](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Sprite.html#pivot) then the rotation?

Comment: Can we see the code?